# Refreshing Ubuntu gnome shell background after coming back from sleep

Tags: scripting, gnome-shell

I'm experiencing a known but very annoying bug with gnome shell where while using Nvidia drivers, every time computer suspends it messes up background image until I manually press Alt + F2 and type r. This is a long know thing but nobody is really trying to fix it.

I would like to write a script that forces the background to reload every time the computer comes back from suspend, but I'm not that acquainted with Linux to do that.

Could anybody help?